# ImproperlyConfigured at /blog/ ошибка: is not a valid regular expression: nothing to repeat

Tags: python, django

Здравствуйте, не могу разобраться в чем причина ошибки:

> "^?P[\w-]+/$" is not a valid regular expression: nothing to repeat

project/urls.py

```
url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
```

app/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^$', 'blog.views.blog', name='blog'),
                       url(r'^?P<slug>[\w-]+/$', 'blog.views.blog_detail', name='blog_detail'),
                       )
```

app/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from blog.models import BlogDjango


def blog(request):
    blog_list = BlogDjango.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog.html', {'blog_list': blog_list})


def blog_detail(request, slug):
    blog = get_object_or_404(BlogDjango, slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'post.html', {'blog': blog})
```

blog.html

```
<a href="{% url 'blog_detail' slug=blog_list.slug %}">{{ db.blog_title }}/a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы из url передать аргументы во view, их нужно заключить в круглые скобки. При этом они передаются как неименованные позиционные. Чтобы передать именнованые аргументы, нужно использовать следующий синтаксис регулярного выражения `(?P<name>pattern)`, где `name` - наименование группы, а `pattern` - шаблон

Таким образом в Вашем url.py должна быть такая строка

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', 'blog.views.blog_detail', name='blog_detail')
```